# General solution to $f(x,y,z) = g(p,q,z)$ for all $x,y,z,p,q$ by method of inexact differential

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have a book that says that if
$$
f(x,y,z) = g(p,q,z)
$$

and

$$
h(x,y,p,q) = 0
$$

then f and g both have the form (for instance):

$$
\phi(x,y)\zeta(z) + \eta(z)
$$

I'm guessing the proof has to do with integrating inexact differentials such as

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\big)_{y,z}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\big)_{x,z}dy =
\frac{\partial g}{\partial p}\big)_{q,z}dp + \frac{\partial g}{\partial q}\big)_{p,z}dq
$$

from cancelling (I think it's true, but can't quite prove) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\big)_{x,y}dz = \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\big)_{p,q}dz$,

subject to

$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\big)_{y,p,q}dx + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\big)_{x,p,q}dy + \frac{\partial h}{\partial p}\big)_{x,y,q}dp + \frac{\partial h}{\partial q}\big)_{x,y,p}dq = 0
$$

Any suggestions?

The book is Theoretical Concepts in Physics by Longair, p. 121

Thanks

Comment: Seems like there is some information missing. $h(x,y,z)=g(p,q,z)$ for all $x,y,z,p,q$?

Comment: Edited question extensively, and I think you're right I should add that to the title.

Comment: Now your subject and body don't agree.

Comment: In what way? I don't quite see what you mean.

Comment: For example, the title says $h(x,y,z)$ and the body says $h(x,y,p,q)$. Does $h$ take four parameters or three?

Comment: erg.  keep changing variables grrrrrrr

Comment: If you're given functions $f$ and $g$, and you know that $f(x, y, z)=g(p, q, z)$ for all choices of $x, y, z, p, q$ then you know that $f(x, y, z)$ doesn't depend on $x$ or $y$ and $g(p, q, z)$ doesn't depend on $p$ or $q$. Or maybe you mean the statements are true for some specific values of $x, \ldots, q$ in which case it's trivially true so that can't be right either.

Comment: I think he means if $f(x,y,z)=g(p,q,z)$ when $h(x,y,p,q)=0$, but I really can't understand the question. Why not post the question exactly as it occurs?

Comment: Here's what I tried to do.  First I laid out the problem exactly as it is stated in the book.  I gave the conclusion the book draws, but said I don't understand how they got it. I proposed a line of attack using inexact differentials. I'm basically looking for the derivation of what the book states.  Sorry if it wasn't more clear.  Maybe I should post a different question asking that exactly.

Comment: Oh, and I mean that if $f(x,y,z) = g(p,q,z)$ for some $x,y,p,q,z$ and $h(x,y,p,q) = 0$, then $f$ has the form $\phi(x,y)\zeta(z) + \eta(z)$. I want to be able to derive that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think I should do that.

Comment: I asked the simplified question here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823266/general-solution-to-fx-y-z-gp-q-z-for-all-x-y-z-p-q-when-hx-y-p-q-0